# How to format dates in data.frame and ggplot?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05"),
             B=c(12.5, 24.5, 23.4, 45.0, 12.0))
```

```
## + > df
##         A    B
## 1 2019-01 12.5
## 2 2019-02 24.5
## 3 2019-03 23.4
## 4 2019-04 45.0
## 5 2019-05 12.0
```

Where column A contains dates (YYYY-MM) and column B the observations corresponding to those dates.

I want to plot the graph using ggplot2 and I need the dates to display along the X axis with the format MM-YY, e.g. `Jan-19`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please look at advice for making a reproducible example. For your example, you may want to look at the lubridate package for working with dates.

Comment: Please always use descriptive titles here. "Who can help me" is not a problem description. However, the problem as is stated is too broad anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider giving us a reproducible example next time and stating your problem in a much more precise way.

Nonetheless, with the information you provide, you could do something as follows:

First, let's make a vector with the correct date data to avoid further problems. I'm assuming your observations are done the first day of the month, so your vector `A` would be something as:

```
A <- paste0(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05"), "-01")
```

If we create directly the data.frame it would be something as:

```
df <- data.frame(A=paste0(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05"), "-01"),
             B=c(12.5, 24.5, 23.4, 45.0, 12.0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Or using `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)
df <- paste0(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05"), "-01") %>%
        data.frame(A=.,B=c(12.5, 24.5, 23.4, 45.0, 12.0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then we format `A` as date:

```
df$A <- as.Date(df$A, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

To plot it you should do something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=A, y=B)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%y", date_breaks = "1 month") +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x="time") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Hope it helps

PS: check out this post regarding [date formats](https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now as I expected.

Comment: You are welcome and I'm glad it is working for you. Please consider then to mark the question answered.  I also have edited your question (both title and content) so it will be helpful for other people having the same problem you had.